# add an image field to admin.auth admin site in django

Tags: django, django-admin, authentication

Hi ive not be able to find any one trying to solve this issue yet so i thought id ask the question here.  Basically im trying to add an image field to the admin.auth users admin site that relates to my userprofile model.

Aswell as users that register to the site, the admins need to be able to specify a profile picture when the create a user in the admin site that will be used for posts they make to news and blogs etc.

Is this at all possible, i have the userprofile model working which will allow me to add the image but i want to include this in the admin user panel when an admin creates a new user.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your UserProfile (with the extra image field) as an [inline](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) to the User adminModel. So when you go to the admin.auth panel to add a new user, there will be an inline below it with all the UserProfile fields.

Something like this should do it (in admin.py of whatever app your userprofile is in):

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin

class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile

class UserModelAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [UserProfileInline,]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User,UserModelAdmin)
```

Comment: Excellent thanks so much, stupidly i never thought of this even though i have used this a lot throughout out the rest of the site!! KUDOS!

Comment: No problem, had the  same problem myself when trying to bend the admin to do what I wanted.